# Are HBITMAPs assigned via SetMenuItemInfo automatically deleted on DestroyMenu()?

Tags: winapi, popupwindow

Using `CreatePopupMenu()` to create `HMENU`, adding text items to it via `AppendMenu()`, then loading an icon, using `GetIconInfo()` to get the bitmap, assigning that bitmap to the `HMENU` via `SetMenuItemInfo()`.   Now I presume I need to keep that `HBITMAP` from `GetIconInfo()` valid so I can't delete it at this time.

The question is does `DestroyMenu()` delete the `HBITMAP` assigned to it, or do I need to loop through the menu and `DeleteObject()` for each item that has an assigned `HBITMAP`?  If I do have to do that, do I have to remove it via setting `HBITMAP` in the `HMENU` to NULL prior to `DeleteObject()` or the fact that after the loop I'll be calling `DestroyMenu()` enough?

TIA!!

Comment: The menu does not assume ownership of the image, which makes sense because one image can be displayed on different menus. You [delete the images separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/using-menus#example-of-menu-item-bitmaps) and you don't have to set the menu structures to null before destroying the menu.